# Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4.0 Release

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Any update regarding the release of Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4.0?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#preface.versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4 will be part of the Spring Data 2021.2 release train. As for the timeline see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-2021.2-(Raj)-Release-Notes-(Preview)#release-dates